# Pandas: Renaming "Unnamed: *" or "NaN" in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, fillna

Here's my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'file.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

I want to rename the "Unnamed: *" columns to the last valid name.

Here's what I've tried and the results:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Unnamed.*', method='ffill')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-253-c868b8bff7c7> in <module>()
----> 1 df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Unnamed.*', method='ffill')

TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'
```

This "works" if I just do

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Unnamed.*', '')
```

But I then have either blank values or NaN (if I replace '' with 'NaN'. And then I try:

```
df.columns = df.columns.fillna('ffill')
```

Which has no effect. So I tried with inplace=True:

df.columns = df.columns.fillna('ffill', inplace=True)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-279-cce486472d5b> in <module>()
----> 1 df.columns = df.columns.fillna('ffill', inplace=True)

TypeError: fillna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'
```

Then I tried a different way:

```
i = 0
while i < len(df.columns):
    if df.columns[i] == 'NaN':
        df.columns[i] = df.columns[i-1]
    print(df.columns[i])
    i += 1
```

Which gives me this Error:

```
Oil
158 RGN Mistura
Access West Winter Blend 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-246-bc8fa6881b1a> in <module>()
      2 while i < len(df.columns):
      3     if df.columns[i] == 'NaN':
----> 4         df.columns[i] = df.columns[i-1]
      5     print(df.columns[i])
      6     i += 1

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2048 
   2049     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
-> 2050         raise TypeError("Index does not support mutable operations")
   2051 
   2052     def __getitem__(self, key):

TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following, i think it maintains the order you seek.

```
df = pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx')
print df


    a   b   c  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4   d  Unnamed: 6   e  Unnamed: 8   f
0  34  13  73         nan         nan  87         nan  76         nan  36
1  70  48   1         nan         nan  88         nan   2         nan  77
2  37  62  28         nan         nan   2         nan  53         nan  60
3  17  97  78         nan         nan  69         nan  93         nan  48
4  65  19  96         nan         nan  72         nan   4         nan  57
5  63   6  86         nan         nan  14         nan  20         nan  51
6  10  67  54         nan         nan  52         nan  48         nan  79


df.columns = pd.Series([np.nan if 'Unnamed:' in x else x for x in df.columns.values]).ffill().values.flatten()
print df


    a   b   c   c   c   d   d   e   e   f
0  34  13  73 nan nan  87 nan  76 nan  36
1  70  48   1 nan nan  88 nan   2 nan  77
2  37  62  28 nan nan   2 nan  53 nan  60
3  17  97  78 nan nan  69 nan  93 nan  48
4  65  19  96 nan nan  72 nan   4 nan  57
5  63   6  86 nan nan  14 nan  20 nan  51
6  10  67  54 nan nan  52 nan  48 nan  79
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that could work:

```
df.columns = df.columns.where(~df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')).to_series().ffill()
```

, full example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['First', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2','Second', 'Unnamed: 3'])

df.columns = df.columns.where(~df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')).to_series().ffill()

print(df.columns)
```

Prints:

```
Index(['First', 'First', 'First', 'Second', 'Second'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into has to do with the fact that columns and the index are `pd.Index` objects. The fillna method of a pandas Index does not take the same arguments that the fillna methods for pandas Series or DataFrame take. 
I made a toy example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
         {'a':[1], 'Unnamed:1':[1], 'Unnamed:2':[1], 'b':[1], 'Unnamed:3':[1]}, 
         columns=['a', 'Unnamed:3', 'Unnamed:1', 'b', 'Unnamed:2']))
df 
#   a  Unnamed:3  Unnamed:1  b  Unnamed:2
#0  1          1          1  1          1
```

Your original regex does not capture the entire column name, let's fix that.

```
df.columns.str.replace('Unnamed:*', '') 
#Index(['a', '3', '1', 'b', '2'], dtype='object')
df.columns.str.replace('Unnamed:\d+', '')
#Index(['a', '', '', 'b', ''], dtype='object')
df.columns.str.replace('Unnamed:.+', '')
#Index(['a', '', '', 'b', ''], dtype='object')
```

Now let's convert the index into a series so we can use the `.replace` and `.fillna` methods of the `pd.Series` and one of the working regexes to replace the column names in question with `ffill`. Finally we convert into a `pd.Index`

```
pd.Index(
    pd.Series(
        df.columns
    ).replace('Unnamed:\d+', np.nan, regex=True).fillna(method='ffill')
)
#Index(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], dtype='object')

df.columns = pd.Index(pd.Series(df.columns).replace('Unnamed:\d+', np.nan, regex=True).fillna(method='ffill'))
df.head() 
#   a  a  a  b  b
#0  1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work. I don't get any errors, it just doesn't make any changes to the data frame. Am I supposed to put a "inplace=True" somewhere? (When I try doing that I get an error)

Comment: Hmm... does my example code not work for you? You just need the following three lines:

`df = pd.DataFrame(
         {'a':[1], 'Unnamed:1':[1], 'Unnamed:2':[1], 'b':[1], 'Unnamed:3':[1]}, 
         columns=['a', 'Unnamed:3', 'Unnamed:1', 'b', 'Unnamed:2']))`
`df.columns = pd.Index(pd.Series(df.columns).replace('Unnamed:\d+', np.nan, regex=True).fillna(method='ffill'))`
`df.head()`